# filled up a column with data on blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

How to use VBA to copy data from i.e sheet2, fill a range (1 column) on blank cells at sheet1

i.e at sheet1 ( -blankcell- = blank)

```
-blankcell-  
-blankcell-  
-blankcell-
ahjefe
-blankcell-
-blankcell-
23234
***fg4
-blankcell-
8569
-blankcell-
```

at sheet2 (data to be used on sheet1 blank cell)

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

END result at sheet1

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ahjefe
aaa
bbb
23234
ccc
aaa
8569
bbb <- stopped at before last blank row
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: +1 on @PowerUser's comment. If you show us what you've tried, we can help you get past your stuck points.

Answer (score 2):

I have some free time, so I wrote this code for you below. However, it's best to always show your efforts when positing questions. Usually people don't just write code for you.

```
Sub FillBlanks()

Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Set wks1 = Sheets(1) 'change to your needs; could also be Sheets("Sheet1") format
Set wks2 = Sheets(2) 'change to your needs; could also be Sheets("Sheet1") format

Dim rngLookup As Range

'assume data on sheet2 is on column A
With wk2
    Set rngLookup = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With wks1

    Dim rngSearch As Range
    'assume blank cells are in column A on sheet 1
    Set rngSearch = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rngSearch = rngSearch.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    Dim cel As Range, i As Integer

    i = 1

    For Each cel In rngSearch

        cel.Value = rngLookup.Cells(i, 1)
        If i = rngLookup.Rows.Count Then i = 1 Else: i = i + 1

    Next


End With

End Sub
```